# "The dimensions of one or more screenshots are wrong." when uploading screenshots to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, screenshot

I am uploading my screenshots to iTunes Connect, and like lots of questions preceding me, I get a "The dimensions of one or more screenshots are wrong." error. The only problem is, I've scoured every resource I could.

Here is what I have:

- 3.5, 4, and 5.5 inch screenshots uploaded fine. I am only getting this error with iPhone 6/4.7 inch screenshots
- I have 4 screenshots set up like the following in JPEG form with 72 DPI:

[image: Dimensions]

Solutions I have tried:

- Renaming the file to "1", "2", ...
- Exporting to both .png and .jpeg formats
- Uploading an archive to iTunes Connect(testing not enabled)
- Waiting between tries
- Tried it on two different iMac computers
- Attempted both on OS X 10.10 and 10.11
- Cleared website data and restarted computer

I am really dumbfounded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I notice your dimensions are 750 x 1344. The iPhone 6 is 750 x 13**3**4.

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2

Comment: Dang. I am a dingus. If anything, my question has a list of needed remedies. I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes

Comment: The number of times I've personally made a mistake, tried some incredibly complicated things to fix it, only to notice that the solution was very obvious is too many to count.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Turns out, I also had a pixel line of alpha on the right edge of 2 of them.

Comment: That link is currently dead.